# Html Table col and row span issue

Tags: html, html-table

Can anyone help me on the following table structure:

[image: click here to see the table structure]

I was unable to achieve that table structure using table row and colspans
Can anyone help me on that...

Comment: Could you show us the Code you were using.

Comment: I have linked a image of an table structure

Comment: Show the code you have tried! This is not a coding service.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<table border="2">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="5">r5 c2</td>
        <td>c2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">c2 r2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c1</td>
        <td>c1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```